# Can there be two embedded mongoose documents with one schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Let's say I have for example:

```
const Stats = Item({
    name: String,
    value: Number
})

const Player = Schema({
    name: String,
    objectInventory: [Item],
    petInventory: [Item]
})
```

Would the items somehow get mixed up? Is this safe? Are all the items unique and know where they belong to? I don't want to write Player.objectInventory and get pets in there. I'm sorry if this seems like common sense but I had that doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there can be two documents in one schema. This items will not get mixed up. The mongoose is nothing more than just another layer on top of the database to help you with schema. So in your case, you would just put different ids for different properties (e.g. objectInventory and petInventory) and when you would populate them, the mongoose will just make correct queries to return the results.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification!